# pop up js code not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement a popup. 
When I click the select country a pop up should display

Here is a link to something I am trying to copy

http://www.teslamotors.com/

I have tried the same JS code in my JSFiddle but don't know what's wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/6QXGG/2/

```
// locale selector actions
$('#region-picker').click(function(){
    var foot_height = $('#footer').innerHeight();
    var foot_height_css = foot_height-12;
    var select_position = '-=' + (Number(400)+18);
    var $selector = $('#locale-select');
    $('#locale_pop').fadeOut();
    $selector.css({top:foot_height_css});
    $selector.fadeIn(function(){
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $(this).animate({top:select_position}, 1000);
        });
});

$('#footer').fadeIn(function(){
    var select_label_width = $('#region-picker .locale-select-lable').outerWidth()+8;
    $('#region-picker').width(select_label_width);
    $('#select-tab').width(select_label_width);
    // // check to see if we need to show the locale blip
    // moved to document.ready
    // checkCookie();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats wrong with the code, May be you can try some plugins like theis,

http://needim.github.com/noty/

Comment: thanks for your reply but i would be great if u tell me how to fix my fiddle code...since i am trying same user experience

Comment: thanks for your reply what did you change but still it does reflect like this pop up http://www.teslamotors.com/ pls help

Comment: i did'nt change anything, the problem is you have given the images in css the wrong path, I just chnaged to correct path

Comment: thanks for your reply i am not able to see any of the links <a class="locale-link ca first plain" rel="en_CA" href="teslamotors.com/en_CA">Canada</a>; http://jsfiddle.net/6QXGG/44/    http://jsfiddle.net/6QXGG/44/embedded/result/